# How to connect to a database in Java ME?

Tags: java, java-me, rms

I am student and am developing a mobile quiz game by using Java ME and NetBeans 6.9. I have to store the questions and answers in a database, and I want to connect my MIDlet to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways .

1. You can use local storage RMS you can use to store data.
2. You can store your data on server and interact using web services.

   - [RMS Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/)
   - [Consuming WebServices in J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/)